# IdentityServer as saas - architectural question

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

We are using IdentityServer to serve our several applications with SSO, with plug ins for different external providers. We have applied ASP.NET Identity to the IdentityServer, but we have no local users, only external providers. So the IdentityServer works as a SSO identity gateway. Each customer has it own set of our applications and a identity server app with database. And a SPA app to get a GUI to the IdentityServer/ASP.NET Identity repository.

If we raise our sight a bit, what saas identity providers could be an alternative for us to instead of hosting our own central identity provider (maintaining the IdentiyServer is actually outside our core business, and should really be outsourced. I mean the identity saas solution should hold a configurable repository that we recognize from IdentityServer and ASP.NET Identity as:

- ApiResources, ApiScopes
- Clients, ClientClaims, ClientCorsOrigins, ClientGrantTypes, ClientPostLogoutRedirectUris, ClientRedirectUris, ClientScopes, ClientSecrets
- IdentityResources, IdentityClaims
- EmailType
- External providers configuration, specific for each providers, as AzureAD, OKTA, Facebook and so on.

Provide a REST API to all the Identity services, and a GUI for all administration.

Seems as a basic question, but I think a lot of companies host their own identityserver but is it really core business? It would be preferable to instead subscribe to the equivalent functionality in a fully configurable saas solution, with one point of communication.

Do you have any experience of such saas services? Please give examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many hosted services exists that provides similar functionality to IdentityServer, some of them are:

- [Auth0](http://www.auth0.com/)
- [Okta](https://www.okta.com/)

But the advantage with IdentityServer is that it is a framework that is very highly configurable allowing you to do way more customization than you can with the cloud based ones.